# Hide A Layout After 10 Seconds In Android?

Tags: android

I have a layout displayed on a button click.I want to hide that layout after 10 seconds.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mVolHandler = new Handler();
    mVolRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mVolLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
}


private OnTouchListener mVolPlusOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mVolLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVolHandler.postDelayed(mVolRunnable, 10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using handler.when I clicks the button the layout is displayed and using handler it is made hidden after 10 seconds.But the problem is that when continuously clicks the button it goes hidden.If button again clicked the layout is displayed but goes hidden before 10 seconds.I want to display the layout for 10 seconds from the last user click.

Comment: I there any other solution?Please help me

Comment: I want to display the layout for 10 seconds from last user click.But on continues clicks it hides before 10seconds and also while clicking

Comment: In that case, you should better [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8177830/edit) your question, and show the code you have used.

Comment: @user987362 : see my edited answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177830/hide-a-layout-after-10-seconds-in-android/8177879#8177879

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make use of [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) & [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html).

You can delay a Runnable using [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) of Handler.

```
Runnable mRunnable;
Handler mHandler=new Handler();

mRunnable=new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                yourLayoutObject.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //If you want just hide the View. But it will retain space occupied by the View.
                yourLayoutObject.setVisibility(View.GONE); //This will remove the View. and free s the space occupied by the View    
            }
        };
```

Now inside onButtonClick event you have to tell Handler to run a runnable after X milli seconds:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,10*1000);
```

If you want to cancel this then you have to use `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`

**Update (According to edited question)**
You just need to remove callbacks from `Handler` using [`removeCallbacks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

So just update your code inside `onTouch` method like this :

```
mVolLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mVolHandler.removeCallbacks(mVolRunnable);
mVolHandler.postDelayed(mVolRunnable, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) started when you click the button, with 10 seconds duration that fades out the layout and probably sets its visibility to `GONE` at the end.

Comment: +1 for providing a good solution. though using a timer also will serve the purpose.. it would have been helpful if you had shown how its actually done..

Comment: Making the layout just disappear is just not elegant that's why I suggested the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `postDelayed`:

```
val delay = 3000L // 3 seconds
view.postDelayed({ view.visibility = View.GONE }, delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler to hide layout after 10 seconds. Use Post delayed method

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loading, Please wait .. ",true);

    setTitle("set title");
    final Handler uiThreadCallback=new Handler();
    final Runnable runInUIThread= new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            fnDraw();
            pd.dismiss();

        }
    }; 
    new Thread(){
        @Override public void run(){
            uiThreadCallback.post(runInUIThread);
        }
    }.start();
}
public void fnDraw(){
    setContentView(R.layout.define ur xml if any);
    i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i1);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

    timerRegister=new Timer();
    lIteration=0;
    checkTime=new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            if(lIteration==1){
                timerRegister.cancel();
                uiDrawThreadCallback.post(runInUIDrawThread);
            }
            lIteration++;
            return;
        }
    };
    timerRegister.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTime,0,10000);
}
final Handler uiDrawThreadCallback=new Handler();
final Runnable runInUIDrawThread= new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        fnDrawAgain();
    }
};
public void fnDrawAgain(){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,new class you want to open.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

try it  m sure it gonna work in ur on create screen