# Execute a Method after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a program that execute a method after 10 seconds, how to do it in java or android???

Comment: Use a `Timer` or a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: You can use Runnable & Handler combination. Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177830/hide-a-layout-after-10-seconds-in-android/8177879#8177879

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/7147289 use it

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), and submit a Runnable or Callable which calls your method.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
  final Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
       final Handler threadHandler = new Handler();
       new Thread() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                       threadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() {

                               }
                       }, 5000);
               }
       }.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) : A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer.

Example: [Schedule Periodic Tasks](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Here's a [tutorial](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) on this.

Answer (score 1):

For android I use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)